# Upgrading Cordova caused Android Platform to stop working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic3:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Cordova CLI      : 6.4.0 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.0.0 ios 4.3.1
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v7.10.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

I then upgraded my Cordova to the latest version (from `6.4.0` to `7.0.1`):

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.3.1
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v7.10.0
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

As you can see, I also upgraded my Android platform from `android 6.0.0` to `android 6.2.3`.

Since then, I cannot get my Cordova plugins to work on Android. iOS and browser all still works fine.

If I run it on an Android device or emulator, it loads the app, but does not show the Splash Screen, or get the Geolocation, allow Firebase login, etc. It looks like all Cordova plugins for Android are not working.

When I run in Android Studio, I get the following over and over in the logs:

> ```
> W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
> ```

It appears as if the install of the latest Android Platform (6.2.3) has broken the app.

Any suggestions welcome.

UPDATE

Now I try uninstall the Android platform and reinstall version 6.0.0. But I get errors:

```
cordova platform remove android
Removing platform android from config.xml file...
Richards-MacBook-Pro:theWhoZoo richardmarais$ ionic cordova platform add android@6.0.0
> cordova platform add android@6.0.0 --save
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform add android@6.0.0 --save (exit code 1):

        Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@6.0.0
        Adding android project...
        Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
            Path: platforms/android
            Package: com.ionicframework.thewhozoo912107
            Name: theWhoZoo
            Activity: MainActivity
            Android target: android-24
        Subproject Path: CordovaLib
        Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
        Installing "cordova-plugin-app-version" for android
        ANDROID_HOME=/Users/richardmarais/Library/Android/sdk/
        JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
        Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-app-version': Error
            at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:90:25)
            at GradleBuilder.prepEnv (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:161:23)
            at Api.module.exports.runClean (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:131:20)
            at /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:391:50
            at _fulfilled (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
            at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
            at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
            at /Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
            at runSingle (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
            at flush (/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
        Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
        Looked here: /Users/richardmarais/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

But:

```
cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 6.0.0
  ios 4.3.1
```

then

```
cordova build android
✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        ANDROID_HOME=/Users/richardmarais/Library/Android/sdk/
        JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
        Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
        Looked here: /Users/richardmarais/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

I check my Android SDK in Android Studio, and I have all the latest installed (Android 6.0, 7.0 & 7.1).

So I upgrade back to the latest Android platform:

```
cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

Now it builds again with no errors, but I sit with the same problem of the Cordova Plugins not working, and the following in the logs:

> `W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread`

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

deleted `node_modules`

```
npm install

ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@latest

ionic cordova build android
```